# searchCallBack is not defined in Rotten Tomatoes API search

Tags: ajax

I am trying to do a search on the Rotten Tomatoes website for their movies and when I try to type in 'TOY' I got a searchCallBack that is not defined the search should return movies that have the word Toy in them. I am completely new to AJAX by the way. I found that error in the developers tools console.

here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    // You will need this API key in order to call the Rotten Tomatoes API.
    var apiKey = *removed for security purposes;
    var baseUrl = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0";

    var moviesSearchUrl = baseUrl + '/lists/movies/box_office.json?apikey=' + apiKey
    document.getElementById('searchBox').addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {

        if (event.which === 13 || event.keyCode === 13) {
            var searchText = this.value;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax("http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json", {
                    q: 'TODO put in search text',
                    page_limit: 10,
                    page: 1,
                    success: seachCallBack(),
                    dataType: 'jsonp'
                });
            });

            // callback for when we get back the results
            function searchCallback(data) {               
                var movies = data.movies;
                $.each(movies, function (index, movie) {
                    $(document.body).append('<h1>' + movie.title + '</h1>');
                    $(document.body).append('<img src="' + movie.posters.thumbnail + '" />');
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Ajax request callback, you have misspelled the function "seachCallBack." If you spell it correctly it should work. It should be "searchCallback"

```
$(function () { 

     var apiKey = "removed for security purposes"; 
     var baseUrl = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0"; 
     var moviesSearchUrl = baseUrl + '/lists/movies/box_office.json?apikey=' + apiKey

    function keydownHandler(evt) {
           if (event.which === 13 || event.keyCode === 13) {
               var searchText = this.value; 
              $.ajax("http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json", { 
                     q: search text, 
                     page_limit: 10, 
                     page: 1, 
                     success: searchCallback, 
                     dataType:"json"
              }); 
        }
    }           

   // callback for when we get back the results 
   function searchCallback(data) { 
        var movies = data.movies; 
        $.each(movies, function (index, movie) { 
           $(document.body).append('<h1>' + movie.title + '</h1>'); 
           $(document.body).append('<img src="' + movie.posters.thumbnail + '" />'); 
        });
     }

    $('#searchBox').addEventListener('keydown', keydownHandler);
 });
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still is giving me the error "searchCallback is not defined" when I search for 'toy' even though I have corrected my spelling.

Comment: Define your callback function outside of the keydown handler.

Comment: You should also move your Ajax call outside of of the Keydown handler. Furthermore, using the $(function (){}) from Jquery uses the document.onReady so you don't need to call it again when defining your Ajax request.

Comment: See my recent edit for the right idea on how to structure your code.